# android - custom camera common solution

Tags: android, android-camera

I am implementing the custom camera. It's working fine but in some mobiles especially in few Samsung mobile we are facing some problems like saving the image as some rotation. Suppose we are taking the picture in portrait mode but the image is saved in landscape mode.

Here I have some doubts.

1. I set the Camera screen activity orientation as portrait. Is it create any problems. Which orientation is good for the activity which having the camera.
2. What's common solution for all mobiles for rotation of image and preview stretch issues.

I tried a lot. My solutions are working in few mobiles only like nexus , Moto G..It fails in Samsung S4 mini, Galaxy Grand Duos 2...

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I implemented one photo take activity which you can take the photo and set the orientation of the photo. It is supported by every device I tested including Samsung galaxy series, tablets, sony xperia series, tablets.

You can check out my accepted answer about rotation of images on this topic:

[Camera capture orientation on samsung devices in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203369/camera-capture-orientation-on-samsung-devices-in-android/18203715#18203715)

**this part is where I set the taken photo to the imageview in the main activity:**

```
            try {
                File imageFile = new File(cursor.getString(0));
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                        imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                }

                Log.v("", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotate);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            testImage.setImageBitmap(null);
            testImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**constant values in camera activity:**

```
  private static final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL =  1;
  private static final int ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED =  2;
  private static final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL =  3;
  private static final int ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED =  4;
  private OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener;
  private int mOrientation =  -1;
```

**callback function in camera activity:**

```
      Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback=new Camera.PictureCallback(){
          public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, final Camera camera){

              dialog=ProgressDialog.show(CameraActivity.this,"","Please wait while the photo is being saved..");
              new Thread(){
                  public void run(){
                      try{
                          Thread.sleep(1000);         
                      }
                      catch(Exception ex){}
                      onPictureTake(data,camera);     
                  }
              }.start();      
          }
      };
```

**take photo function in camera activity:**

```
      public void onPictureTake(byte[] data, Camera camera){
          switch (mOrientation) {
          case ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL:
              rotate = 90;
              break;
          case ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL:
              rotate = 0;
              break;
          case ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED:
              rotate = 270;
              break;
          case ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED:
              rotate = 180;
              break;
          }

          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
          matrix.postRotate(rotate);
          bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
          bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
          mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
          savePhoto(mutableBitmap);
          dialog.dismiss();
          flag = 0;
          finish();
      }
```

**orientation listenner which is called in onresume in camera activity:**

```
mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

                    // determine our orientation based on sensor response
                    int lastOrientation = mOrientation;

                    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();   
                    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                    System.out.println(rotation+"");

                if (display.getOrientation() != Surface.ROTATION_0) {   // landscape oriented devices
                        System.out.println("LANDSCAPE");
                        if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {                         
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
                            }
                        } else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
                            }                       
                        } else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;
                            }                       
                        } else if (orientation <135 && orientation > 45) { 
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
                            }                       
                        }                       
                    } else {  // portrait oriented devices
                        System.out.println("PORTRAIT");
                        if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {                          
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
                            }
                        } else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
                            }                       
                        } else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
                            }                       
                        } else if (orientation <135 && orientation > 45) { 
                            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {
                                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;
                            }                       
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
```

If you also need to save and use that image that you have rotated, saving and using the photo functions additional to my answer I gave above:

**savePhoto function:**

```
public void savePhoto(Bitmap bmp) {

        imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                cc.getDirectoryName());
        imageFileFolder.mkdir();
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                + fromInt(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, date.toString() + ".jpg");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            scanPhoto(imageFileName.toString());
            out = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**scanPhoto function:**

```
public void scanPhoto(final String imageFileName) {
        geniusPath = imageFileName;
        msConn = new MediaScannerConnection(MyClass.this,
                new MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                        msConn.scanFile(imageFileName, null);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                        msConn.disconnect();

                    }
                });
        msConn.connect();
    }
```

**SavePhotoTask class:**

```
class SavePhotoTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "photo.jpg");
            if (photo.exists()) {
                photo.delete();
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(photo.getPath());
                fos.write(jpeg[0]);
                fos.close();
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            }
            return (null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I set the activity orientation in manifest file as Portrait. Can I declare it? because I don't want it in landscape. I mean here I restricted it in portrait.

Comment: My activity is portrait as well