# Android video recorded using mediaRecorder and surface view doesn't play in Landscape View although recorded in Portrait View

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I am working on an app where I have to record a video which is supposed to be in `Portrait View` specifically and play it in `Portrait View` as well. I'm using `mediaRecorder` to record the video.

Have used this site for reference: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/android-video-capture-example/

and made slight changes to suit my requirements:

Here is the code:

For the camera I use these settings:

```
mCamera = Camera.open(findFrontFacingCamera());
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            Camera.Parameters params= mCamera.getParameters();
            params.set("rotation", 90);
            params.set("orientation", "portrait");
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that video gets recorded (what seems to be) in `Portrait View` but when I play it using any player for eg. MX Player I get a video that is recorded/played in `Landscape View`.

Here are the screens for reference:

[image: The recording Screen]

The video played:
[image]

I have used the `setDisplayOrientation(90)` parameter but its not working.
How do I achieve that I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike iOS camera, we cannot truly choose portrait camera frame orientation on Android.

`Camera.setDisplayOrientation()` only refers to the orientation of live video preview from camera; the actual frame data is never rotated on Android. You can see it if you use an onPreviewFrame() callback. [`Camera.setRotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29) only effects the `onPictureTaken()` callback, and on majority of devices only sets an EXIF rotation flag.

Setting "rotation" and "orientation" explicitly by name is dangerous: some devices may recognize these keys, other will silently ignore them, while yet other ROMs may throw a RuntimeException when the `Camera.setParameters()` params with unexpected key or value is received. But at any rate, I have never seen an Android device that changes the recorded video frames when any of these flags.

You have the [`MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint(int)) API, but it will not rotate the frames of recorded video, only put a flag in the video header.

So, unfortunately you must rotate the video on the receiving side. This depends on the way you render your video, and yes, you can check the orientation hint if you want.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how  I can do it by myself ? Any reference source you know of?

Comment: also I have already used setOrientationHint() but its still not working.

Comment: what do you mean "not working"? Do you check this flag on the receiver?

Comment: How do you render the video? If you use OpenGL texture, you can apply a transformation matrix, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518560/inconsistent-video-rotation-when-using-mediacodec

Comment: I have simply recorded the video with setOrientationHint(90) and tried playing the video on default player and MX player but in both the video is still getting played in Landscape mode and not Portrait mode. I'm not rendering it myself at this point of time.

Comment: According to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61382/is-there-a-video-player-that-supports-the-orientation-flag, MX Player has this support. Please check that the flag is actually set in your video. Note that you must set it early, it will not change the clip that is being recorded!

Comment: `mCamera.unlock();
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface()
mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
`

This is prepared well before I call `mediaRecorder.start()`

I confirmed it using a debugger

Comment: I think I got what the problem is. I had been testing the app on my Nexus 7 running 6.0.1. When I tested on other devices: Samsung S3, Panasonic Eluga One, Asus Zenphone 2, MI4i, Moto G3, I found that its working properly. So I think there's problem with nexus 7. Thanks for the help !